# How to import ag-grid-module in angular?

Tags: angular

`Cannot find module 'ag-grid-angular' or its corresponding type declarations.`
this error is showing when importing it in app module although I have already installed the module

I tried to import like this import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular/lib/ag-grid-angular.module';
and the error goes away but idk if this approach is right or wrong